# What are Islamic guidelines about online 'Akhlaq' (relevant on internet in general and this site in particular)?

Tags: sharia

What are Islamic guidelines about online 'Akhlaq' (relevant on internet in general and this site in particular) ?

How much this new medium of communication comes under husn-e-khulq (having good etiquettes and manners in dealing with people) ?